# Problemas con el refresco de pantalla usando el componente TVertScrollBox

Tags: android, scroll, delphi

Estoy haciendo una aplicación en la que tiene un `Form` que muestra datos de configuración, tiene bastantes campos, utilizo `TEdit` y `TCheckBox`, metidos en un `TFramedVertScrollBox`. También lo he probado con `TVertScrollBox`.

El problema que tengo es que cuando desplazo la pantalla y se esconden los *CheckBox*. Cuando vuelven a mostrarse aparecen chequeados, vuelvo a esconderlos, y aparecen sin *check*, y así van cambiando según vaya moviendo el *scroll*.

Hay veces que los componentes se descolocan, no ocurre siempre, pero con los *CheckBox* es siempre.

Nota: Utilizo *Delphi 10.2 Versión 25.0.26309.314*.

Comment: Nunca he visto un comportamiento como el que mencionas. ¿Es algo solamente visual o la propiedad `checked` está cambiando también constantemente?

Comment: Es algo solamente visual, no cambia el checked, sigue teniendo su valor, es a la hora de dibujar, he visto que en la correcciones de errores de la siguiente versión de delphi han corregido ese error en el componente, justo ese error, "problemas al dibujar los Checkbox", y otro problema mas que habia con otro componente, solo a la hora de dibujar, así que tendré que probar con la siguiente versión de Delphi (http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/New_features_and_customer_reported_issues_fixed_in_RAD_Studio_10.3)